# How do you change the line color in wijmo?

Tags: wijmo

I'm doing a line graph in wijmo, and it works great, but I can't find an area of documentation or a sample that tells me how to change the color of the lines. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the 'stroke' option in the seriesStyles collection of WijLineChart. You may refer to the following sample implementing the same:
http://wijmo.com/demo/explore/?widget=LineChart&sample=Stroke%20styles

Comment: That is not where i would have expected it to be.  I'll try this soon and accept your answer if it works.